# How do I write a function that takes a range or list of arguments in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, range, vba

With `SUM` for instance, I can do things like:

```
=SUM(F5:F7,F6:F8,A1,E7:G7,F7,2,7)
```

Which takes multiple ranges and/or individual cells and it adds them all up.  My question is how do I do this with a VBA function, e.g. to generalize a binary XOR:

```
Function BXOR(A As Integer, B As Integer) As Integer
    BXOR = CLng(A) Xor CLng(B)
End Function
```

It gets old fast when I have to `=BXOR(BXOR(BXOR(w,x),y),z)`

---

#### Generalized version of Marco's function:

```
Function BXOR(ParamArray vars() As Variant) As Long
    Dim i,j As Long
    BXOR = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(vars)
        If Not IsObject(vars(i)) Then
            ' Handle explicitly passed integer arguments, e.g. BXOR(1,[...])
            BXOR = BXOR Xor CLng(vars(i))
        ElseIf IsArray(vars(i).Value2) Then
            ' Handle 1-D ranges of cells, e.g. BXOR(A1:A3,[...])
            For j = 1 To UBound(vars(i).Value2)
                BXOR = BXOR Xor CLng(vars(i)(j).Value2)
            Next j
        Else
            ' Handle individual cells, e.g. BXOR(A1,[...])
            BXOR = BXOR Xor CLng(vars(i).Value2)
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are looking for a [ParamArray](http://www.bygsoftware.com/Excel/VBA/paramarray.htm)

Your code should look like this:

```
Function BXor(ParamArray vars() As Variant) as Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(vars)
        tmp = tmp Xor clng(vars(i))
    Next

    BXor = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: Works well for any number (0+) of cells, but is there any way to determine if one of the ParamArray elements is a range (e.g. `A1:A3`) instead of a number and iterate through it?

Comment: You should use "isObject" function. 
And if you want to be sure that it is a Excel.Range, you can use "TypeName" function.

Comment: It seems like I needed to handle the arguments three different ways; see question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParamArray` to pass a variable number of arguments. The type has to be `Variant`.

```
Function BXOR(ParamArray args() As Variant)
```